# Run specific apex tests during "sfdx force:source:deploy"

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Since summer 19, `sfdx force:source:deploy` allows us to push source format meta-data into static orgs and production. The Commands are introduced [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_build_mdapi_production.htm)

However when I check the help of `sfdx force:source:deploy`, it seems the lowest number of Apex tests that you can run is `--testlevel RunLocalTests`.

Is it possible to set it to run only specific apex tests when deploying into a production org?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Now with the latest sfdx update(7.21.0) you can run 'sfdx force:source:deploy' command with specific test classes. Check below command.

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p "./PathToMetadata" -l RunSpecifiedTests -r TestClass1,TestClass2 -w 33 --verbose --loglevel fatal
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm

Comment: Additionally, you can run specific methods from the test class, instead of the default "all methods" -   RunSpecifiedTests -r TestClass1.method1,TestClass2

Answer (score 7):

[force:source:deploy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_deploy) does let you run specific tests by setting `--testlevel` to `RunSpecifiedTests` and then specifying the tests with the `--runtests` argument.

So you could do something like `sfdx force:source:deploy --checkonly --sourcepath force-app --targetusername production-org --testlevel RunSpecifiedTests --runtests MyUnitTests` to do a validation and run specific tests.

Comment: what is MyUnitTests its a test package name?

Comment: No, it's the name of a test class. If you want to run tests from multiple classes you can use a comma separated list instead.

Comment: can we make `--runtests MyUnitTests` this part of command dynamic? Like point to a specific folder.

Comment: The `--runtests` parameter only takes a comma separated list of tests, so there's nothing built into the CLI for passing in a folder - but if you have the tests you want to run in a specific folder there's nothing stopping you from using a script to build a comma separated list of test class names from the files in that folder and passing that list to the command.

Answer (score 0):

Due to updates in SF CLI toolkit, Adding new format for deployment using SF toolkit.

**Syntax**: sf project deploy start -d "relative file path" "relative file 2 path" -l RunSpecifiedTests -t test_class_name

**Example**: sf project deploy start -d "force-app/main/default/classes/Sample.cls" "force-app/main/default/classes/SampleTest.cls" -l RunSpecifiedTests -t SampleTest